# Is this attempt to implement real randomness valid?

Tags: python, random, random-seed, python-sounddevice

Pseudo-randomness becomes real randomness with the lack of an actual pattern in the series of generated values; so essentially the sequence of random elements that repeats itself is potentially infinite.

I know that the way *random.py* `seed()`s is designed to get as far as possible from the 'pseudo' character (i.e. using current timestamp, machine parameters, etc.) which is fine for the widest majority of cases, but what if one needs to mathematically **ensure zero predictability**?

I've read that real randomness can be achieved when we `seed()` based on particular physical events such as *radioactive decay*, but what if, e.g., I used an **array deriving from a recorded audio stream**?

The following is an example of how I'm overriding default `random.seed()` behaviour for this purpose. I'm using `sounddevice` library which implements bindings to services responsible for managing I/O sound devices.

```
# original random imports here
# ...

from sounddevice import rec

__all__ = ["module level functions here"]

# original random constants here
# ...

# sounddevice related constants
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# FS: Sampling Frequency in Hz (samples per second);
# DURATION: Duration of the recorded audio stream (seconds);
# *Note: changing the duration will result in a slower generator, since
# the seed method must wait for the entire stream to be recorded
# before processing further.
# CHANNELS: N° of audio channels used by the recording function (_rec);
# DTYPE: Data type of the np.ndarray returned by _rec;
# *Note: dtype can also be a np.dtype object. E.g., np.dtype("float64").

FS = 48000 
DURATION = 0.1
CHANNELS = 2 
DTYPE = 'float64'


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# The class implements a custom random generator with a seed obtained
# through the default audio input device.
# It's a subclass of random.Random that overrides only the seed method;
# it records an audio stream with the default parameters and returns the
# content in a newly created np.ndarray.
# Then the array's elements are added together and some transformations
# are performed on the sum, in order to obtain a less uniform float.
# This operation causes the randomness to concern the decimal part in
# particular, which is subject to high fluctuation, even when the noise
# of the surrounding environment is homogeneous over time.
# *Note: the blocking parameter suspends the execution until the entire
# stream is recorded, otherwise the np array will be partially empty.
# *Note: when the seed argument is specified and different than None,
# SDRandom will behave exactly like its superclass

class SDRandom(Random):

    def seed(self, a=None, version=2):
        if isinstance(a, type(None)):
            stream = rec(frames=round(FS * DURATION),
                         samplerate=FS,
                         channels=CHANNELS,
                         dtype=DTYPE,
                         blocking=True
                         )

            # Sum and Standard Deviation of the flattened ndarray.
            sum_, std_ = stream.sum(), stream.std() 

            # round() determines the result's sign.
            b = sum_ - round(sum_)

            # Collecting a number of exponents based on the std' digits.
            e = [1 if int(c) % 2 else -1 for c in str(std_).strip("0.")]

            a = b * 10 ** sum(e)

        super().seed(a)


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create one instance, seeded from an audio stream, and export its
# methods as module-level functions.
# The functions share state across all uses.

_inst = SDRandom()
# binding class methods to module level functions here
# ...

## ------------------------------------------------------
## ------------------ fork support  ---------------------

if hasattr(_os, "fork"):
    _os.register_at_fork(after_in_child=_inst.seed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _test() # See random._test() definition.
```

And my implementation still doesn't achieve genuine randomness according to the theory. How is this possible? How could audio inputs be deterministic in any way, even when considering the following?

> This operation causes the randomness to concern the decimal part in
> particular, which is subject to high fluctuation, even when the noise
> of the surrounding environment is homogeneous over time.

Comment: Changing how you seed the PRNG doesn't make it truly random. It still uses a PRNG to get the sequence of numbers after it's seeded.

Comment: If you want zero predictability as of now, measure a spin of a quantum particle.

Comment: @Barmar but isn't predictability more related to the seed than the actual algorithms of the generator?

Comment: @CaptainTrojan Yes that's exactly the type of events that I've read being *truly* random

Comment: If someone understands how your PRNG works, they just need to observe a finite set of values to calculate the rest.

Comment: @MaxShouman Sorry, I didn't mean to confuse. I meant *unpredictable*, not *truly random*. Noone knows whether the latter is true or false, we know that the first is, at least right now.

Comment: Linux has `/dev/random`, which provides a source of truly random data based on environmental noise.

Comment: A PRNG produces a cycle of values. The seed just picks the starting point of that cycle.

Comment: I tried this on my machine and the seed it generates is always `0.0`

Comment: @CaptainTrojan then what if one wraps all random methods in a decorator that seeds at each invocation?

Comment: @thatotherguy I've checked it rn it works, you might need to inspect if your stream is empty. Maybe it's not recording anything

Comment: @MaxShouman Seeds at invocation? What seeds? *Truly random*? XD

Comment: @CaptainTrojan lol, got it XD

Comment: A key point to realize, Max, that `seeding` is just a way for you, the user, to choose your `pseudo-random` path. That path is very, very deterministic. A PRNG gets you absolutely nowhere. The `P` might as well stand for Predictable.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan lmao predictable is on point. Now I've a clearer view of what happens under random's hood, thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: You're welcome broski (y)

Comment: @Barmar `/dev/urandom` would likely be a better suggestion, very little code should be using `/dev/random` these days

Comment: @SamMason True, although they both use the same source of randomness, which was my main point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off just using the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module for "real" randomness.  This provides you with data from your kernel's [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically-secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), which should be constantly be gathering and mixing in new entropy in a way designed to make life very hard of any attacker.

Your use of infinite isn't appropriate either, you can't run something for "infinitely long" the heat death of the universe will happen a long time before then.

Using the standard Mersenne Twister (as Python's `random` module does) also seems inappropriate, as an attacker can recover the state after drawing just [624 variates](https://blog.ollien.com/posts/reverse-mersenne-twister/).  Using a CSPRNG would make this much harder, and constantly mixing in new state, as your kernel probably does, further hardens this.

Finally, treating the samples as floats then taking the mean and standard-deviation doesn't seem appropriate.  You'd be much better off leaving them as ints and just passing them through a cryptographic hash.  For example:

```
import hashlib
import random

import sounddevice as sd

samples = sd.rec(
    frames=1024,
    samplerate=48000,
    channels=2,
    dtype='int32',
    blocking=True,
)

rv = int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(samples).digest(), 'little')
print(rv)

random.seed(rv)
print(random.random())
```

But then again, please just use `secrets`, it's a much better option.

Note: recent versions of Linux, Windows, OSX, FreeBSD, OpenBSD kernels all work as I've described above.  They make good attempts at gathering entropy, and mix into a CSPRNG in sensible way; for example, see [Fortuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)).

Comment: Very clear and comprehensive answer, thank you! Definitely gonna delve into `secrets`' secrets :)

Comment: Also, didn't think about hashing the values that's actually great, it will save me the trouble of playing with arbitrary algorithms in a vain attempt of diversifying values.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function might be another useful construction to know about.  https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/bit_generators/chacha.html is a CSPRNG that might be interesting as well